# Ошибка "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'follow_player"' в Python

Tags: python, arcade

Разрабатывая простую аркадную игру с помощью библиотеки Arcade для Python, я столкнулся с такой трудностью:

Мне нужно вызвать метод объекта класса в функции другого класса, но python его не видит. Каким образом можно "открыть" метод follow_player() для rocket?

```
class MyGame(arcade.View):
    def __init__(self):

            self.rocket.list = arcade.SpriteList()
            self.rocket = None

            # Создание ракет
            for i in range(ROCKET_COUNT):

            # Создаем экземпляр ракеты
                 rocket = Rocket("assets/Rocket2.png", SPRITE_SCALING_ROCKET)
                 # Позиция ракеты
                 rocket.center_x = self.player_sprite.center_x + 
                                   random.choice([random.randint(-1500, -500),                                                    
                                   random.randint(500, 1500)])

                 rocket.center_y = self.player_sprite.center_y + 
                                   random.choice([random.randint(-1500, -500),                                                                          
                                   random.randint(500, 1500)])
                 rocket.angle = 180

                 # Добавляем ракеты в список для ракет
                 self.rocket_list.append(rocket)

    def on_update(self, delta_time):
            for rocket in self.rocket_list:
                self.rocket.follow_player(self.player_sprite)

class Rocket(arcade.Sprite):
    """ Класс ракеты """

    def follow_player(self, player_sprite):
        """ Функция перемещения ракеты к игроку (аргумент функции) """

        # траектория ракеты, обусловленная изменениями координат
        self.center_x += self.change_x
        self.center_y += self.change_y

        start_x = self.center_x
        start_y = self.center_y

        # Получение места назначения для ракеты #destination
        dest_x = player_sprite.center_x
        dest_y = player_sprite.center_y

        # Расчет: как доставить ракету в пункт назначения (к игроку)
        # Расчет угла(по которому будет двигаться ракета) в радианах между
        # начальными точками и конечными точками.
        x_diff = dest_x - start_x
        y_diff = dest_y - start_y

        # расчет угла
        n = 2.25  # 2.25
        angle = math.atan2(y_diff + n, x_diff + n)

        # С учетом угла вычислим наше изменение х и изменение у.
        self.change_x = math.cos(angle) * ROCKET_SPEED - n
        self.change_y = math.sin(angle) * ROCKET_SPEED - n

        angle_rad = math.radians(self.angle)
        self.angle += self.change_angle

        self.center_x += -ROCKET_SPEED * math.sin(angle_rad)  # * random.randint(1, 3)
        self.center_y += ROCKET_SPEED * math.cos(angle_rad)  # * random.randint(1, 3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас ошибка в теле цикла, вот здесь:

```
def on_update(self, delta_time):
    for rocket in self.rocket_list:
        self.rocket.follow_player(self.player_sprite)
```

В теле цикла вы обращаетесь к атрибуту класса `self.rocket`, а не к переменной `rocket`. Правильнее будет так:

```
def on_update(self, delta_time):
    for rocket in self.rocket_list:
        rocket.follow_player(self.player_sprite)
```

---

По поводу предупреждения, которое возникнет после исправления:

> Unresolved attribute reference 'follow_player' for class 'Sprite'

Судя по [примеру](http://arcade.academy/examples/sprite_follow_simple_2.html#sprite-follow-simple-2) из документации библиотеки описывать окружение игры и инициализировать переменные надо в методе `setup`. Например:

```
class MyGame(arcade.Window):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, SCREEN_TITLE)

        self.rocket_list = None

    def setup(self):
        self.rocket_list = arcade.SpriteList()

        # ...

    def on_update(self, delta_time):
        for rocket in self.rocket_list:
            rocket.follow_player(self.player_sprite)
```

В этом случае предупреждения возникать не будет.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, описав решение по поводу предупреждения.